# Water simulation does not flow into the bucket

Tags: fluid-simulation

I wanted to make a simple scene where water is flowing into a bucket. I had set the domain nicely outside the obstacle i.e., the bucket and a small uv sphere as the inflow. After that when I bake it, the water doesn't even go into the bucket it just flows away from it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, all I had to do was change the Volume initialization to **shell** rather than **Volume** or **both** in the obstacle type and its logical too as, now only the exterior part of the mesh will be used as an obstacle thus allowing the fluid to go inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

The collision shape of the bucket is probably not set correctly. It needs to be set to "Mesh" and not "Cube", "Convex Hull", or any of the other options.

Seem my answer to [What causes this weird collission?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102355/what-causes-this-weird-collision/102361#102361) for a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: See my answer at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102355/what-causes-this-weird-collision/102361#102361 for a more thorough explanation.